# What iPhone maps app can I use if I don't have a SIM card?

Tags: iphone, gps, maps, mapping

I'm going to be using my iPhone overseas without a SIM card, but I want to use turn-by-turn navigation to walk and drive around.

I'm willing to plot my route via wifi before I leave the house, but I won't have internet because my phone won't have a SIM card.

Answer (score 1):

- [Navigon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/navigon-usa/id384680007?mt=8)
- [TomTom](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id326075661?mt=8)
- <sub>[CoPilot](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/copilot-gps-plan-explore-offline/id504677517?mt=8)</sub>*

[Navigon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/navigon-usa/id384680007?mt=8) offers different apps for worldwide coverage.

Depending on where you are headed [TomTom](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id326075661?mt=8) has several different apps for particular regions. Scroll down on the iTunes page to see some options.

*It appears that [CoPilot](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/navigon-usa/id384680007?mt=8) offers directions when offline, but not turn-by-turn directions.

On all of these apps be sure to check and verify that they provide maps for the country (or countries) that you will be visiting.